# Separating data frame into 10-day intervals by ID

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

I have a data frame that I would like to separate into 10-day intervals organized by ID. When I use the code below it separates it by ID, but its not in 10-day intervals for each element in the list, and its not organized by ID.

How could I break my data into 10-day intervals and group them by ID?

```
library(lubridate)
date <- rep_len(seq(dmy("26-12-2010"), dmy("20-12-2013"), by = "days"), 500)
ID <- rep(seq(1, 5), 100)

df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
                 y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
                 ID)

t <- unique(df$date)[seq(from = 1, 
                    to = length(unique(df$date)),
                    by = 10)]


interval_10 <- lapply(
  1:(length(t)-1),
  function(k) df %>% 
    filter(date == t)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this kind of output?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

date <- rep_len(seq(dmy("26-12-2010"), dmy("20-12-2013"), by = "days"), 500)
ID <- rep(seq(1, 5), 100)

df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
                 y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
                 ID)

df %>% 
    mutate(interval = map(1:50, ~rep(.x, 10)) %>% reduce(c)) %>% 
    group_split(interval) %>%
    map(~arrange(.x, ID)) %>% 
    head(5)
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>    date            x       y    ID interval
#>    <date>      <dbl>   <dbl> <int>    <int>
#>  1 2010-12-26 75235. 810405.     1        1
#>  2 2010-12-31 78964. 825454.     1        1
#>  3 2010-12-27 63564. 886938.     2        1
#>  4 2011-01-01 70658. 863580.     2        1
#>  5 2010-12-28 73647. 845554.     3        1
#>  6 2011-01-02 60750. 841294.     3        1
#>  7 2010-12-29 69549. 826752.     4        1
#>  8 2011-01-03 63391. 806722.     4        1
#>  9 2010-12-30 62584. 818130.     5        1
#> 10 2011-01-04 79600. 823551.     5        1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>    date            x       y    ID interval
#>    <date>      <dbl>   <dbl> <int>    <int>
#>  1 2011-01-05 68145. 806577.     1        2
#>  2 2011-01-10 73122. 845198.     1        2
#>  3 2011-01-06 65635. 833174.     2        2
#>  4 2011-01-11 61972. 846711.     2        2
#>  5 2011-01-07 73767. 888569.     3        2
#>  6 2011-01-12 64636. 866264.     3        2
#>  7 2011-01-08 69169. 810342.     4        2
#>  8 2011-01-13 79168. 885329.     4        2
#>  9 2011-01-09 60065. 858075.     5        2
#> 10 2011-01-14 79825. 809081.     5        2
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>    date            x       y    ID interval
#>    <date>      <dbl>   <dbl> <int>    <int>
#>  1 2011-01-15 60489. 878544.     1        3
#>  2 2011-01-20 79112. 803445.     1        3
#>  3 2011-01-16 64206. 824595.     2        3
#>  4 2011-01-21 73777. 893237.     2        3
#>  5 2011-01-17 60151. 885401.     3        3
#>  6 2011-01-22 60348. 829403.     3        3
#>  7 2011-01-18 76682. 869436.     4        3
#>  8 2011-01-23 64845. 885666.     4        3
#>  9 2011-01-19 64418. 847046.     5        3
#> 10 2011-01-24 69272. 857423.     5        3
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>    date            x       y    ID interval
#>    <date>      <dbl>   <dbl> <int>    <int>
#>  1 2011-01-25 62626. 845889.     1        4
#>  2 2011-01-30 67183. 851174.     1        4
#>  3 2011-01-26 67983. 806809.     2        4
#>  4 2011-01-31 75358. 805705.     2        4
#>  5 2011-01-27 60954. 854788.     3        4
#>  6 2011-02-01 67305. 816768.     3        4
#>  7 2011-01-28 79795. 887996.     4        4
#>  8 2011-02-02 63193. 818398.     4        4
#>  9 2011-01-29 66437. 850248.     5        4
#> 10 2011-02-03 68542. 848168.     5        4
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>    date            x       y    ID interval
#>    <date>      <dbl>   <dbl> <int>    <int>
#>  1 2011-02-04 72750. 839064.     1        5
#>  2 2011-02-09 68292. 816603.     1        5
#>  3 2011-02-05 62712. 859081.     2        5
#>  4 2011-02-10 62533. 863694.     2        5
#>  5 2011-02-06 64920. 808720.     3        5
#>  6 2011-02-11 78642. 871171.     3        5
#>  7 2011-02-07 78125. 849347.     4        5
#>  8 2011-02-12 64352. 842637.     4        5
#>  9 2011-02-08 74452. 813705.     5        5
#> 10 2011-02-13 78086. 874101.     5        5
```

Edit:

```
df %>% 
    mutate(interval = map(1:50, ~rep(.x, 10)) %>% reduce(c)) %>% 
    group_split(interval) %>%
    map(~arrange(.x, ID)) %>% 
    map(~ group_split(.x, ID)) %>% 
    head(2)
#> [[1]]
#> <list_of<
#>   tbl_df<
#>     date    : date
#>     x       : double
#>     y       : double
#>     ID      : integer
#>     interval: integer
#>   >
#> >[5]>
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   date            x       y    ID interval
#>   <date>      <dbl>   <dbl> <int>    <int>
#> 1 2010-12-26 64016. 858085.     1        1
#> 2 2010-12-31 76973. 810635.     1        1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   date            x       y    ID interval
#>   <date>      <dbl>   <dbl> <int>    <int>
#> 1 2010-12-27 73318. 818689.     2        1
#> 2 2011-01-01 63646. 804369.     2        1
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   date            x       y    ID interval
#>   <date>      <dbl>   <dbl> <int>    <int>
#> 1 2010-12-28 77786. 870629.     3        1
#> 2 2011-01-02 63465. 820951.     3        1
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   date            x       y    ID interval
#>   <date>      <dbl>   <dbl> <int>    <int>
#> 1 2010-12-29 62191. 851103.     4        1
#> 2 2011-01-03 69102. 874624.     4        1
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   date            x       y    ID interval
#>   <date>      <dbl>   <dbl> <int>    <int>
#> 1 2010-12-30 71665. 867749.     5        1
#> 2 2011-01-04 67052. 861228.     5        1
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> <list_of<
#>   tbl_df<
#>     date    : date
#>     x       : double
#>     y       : double
#>     ID      : integer
#>     interval: integer
#>   >
#> >[5]>
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   date            x       y    ID interval
#>   <date>      <dbl>   <dbl> <int>    <int>
#> 1 2011-01-05 66203. 830146.     1        2
#> 2 2011-01-10 63117. 867473.     1        2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   date            x       y    ID interval
#>   <date>      <dbl>   <dbl> <int>    <int>
#> 1 2011-01-06 64386. 810594.     2        2
#> 2 2011-01-11 63491. 839683.     2        2
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   date            x       y    ID interval
#>   <date>      <dbl>   <dbl> <int>    <int>
#> 1 2011-01-07 70155. 865205.     3        2
#> 2 2011-01-12 74384. 833320.     3        2
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   date            x       y    ID interval
#>   <date>      <dbl>   <dbl> <int>    <int>
#> 1 2011-01-08 63251. 853296.     4        2
#> 2 2011-01-13 70607. 803073.     4        2
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   date            x       y    ID interval
#>   <date>      <dbl>   <dbl> <int>    <int>
#> 1 2011-01-09 64284. 889136.     5        2
#> 2 2011-01-14 63190. 866626.     5        2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I think this is close to what I was looking for. For each element in a list, I was hoping to get every observation within a 10-day time frame for a single ID. Is that something that could be done?

Comment: @JohnHuang i added an edit with an additional split.

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
     group_by(ID) %>%
     mutate(new = ceiling_date(date, '10 day'))
```

Comment: I was hoping create a list with the 10-day intervals and within the list to get every observation within a 10-day time frame for a single ID in a single element of the list. For example, in the list for the first element, I would like to get all the dates within a 10-day time frame for `ID` 1. In the second element, I would like to get all the dates within the next 10-day time frame for `ID` 1. Then so forth until `ID` 1 is done. Is that something that could be done?

Comment: @JohnHuang you can create `interval` using that list of  values with `map2` and filter based on that